# How to check impersonation in SugarCRM by Code?

Tags: c#, javascript, soap, sugarcrm

I want to check that if impersonation is enabled in SugarCRM site by code (C# or JavaScript).
I have searched lot in google but I am not able to find anything for that.

I am using the SugarCRM's soap api. From that I want to find out the way that if the SugarCRM site is accessible with impersonation.

The soap api I am using with C# and JavaScript.

Is there any way to find out this?

I have checked a Link which shows steps for how to check impersonation.
http://kb.omni-ts.com/entry/94/